# HP Service Test - Call Java Class service - having class path issues

Tags: java, testing

I am currently using HP Service Test 11.10 to test a call to a web interface, but as part of this test I'm adding some data to an oracle Database, which by default HPST does not support. HPST does support calls to a java class, so I'm attempting to call a Java class in a .JAR file. I have placed this .JAR file in the directory with my test solution. When I add a step to Call Java Class I can select and run the file just fine, but I'm having a problem where I cannot move my test solution to a different directory without getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I run my test.

As near as I can tell, it's trying to call the specific path for the .JAR when I add it (I.E. something like c:\temp{test directory}, even though I may have moved it to c:\users{user name}\workspace{test directory}). How can I change this so that it always looks in the same directory as the test solution for this .JAR file?
....

Answer (score 1):

From the HP Software Solutions Community forum:

> Hello, You are right, the path of the .jar file is indeed preserved
>   within the test as it is translated to code. This path cannot be
>   modified, and there's no way to add jar paths relatively to the test
>   path.
>
> But still, one workaround I can think of is to include this jar in
>   what we call InternalJavaClasspath:
>
> You can define a new path to that jar of yours within
>   InternalJavaClasspath.dat located under
>   {hp_service_test_installation_folder}\dat And then you must put this
>   jar in a subfolder under the installation folder.
>
> The common location is: bin/java - you can create a folder here called
>   MySpecialJars and the respective line in the dat file will be:
>   bin/java/MySpecialJars/MySpecialJar01.jar